# STS - Build On Save

Tags: eclipse, grails, build, save, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have inherited a Grails project and am pretty new to Grails as well as Eclipse.  I have the project in STS 2.6.1.  Every time I save a file the project does a complete compilation from scratch.  I have unchecked Project -> Build Automatically.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound right.  There should be an incremental compilation occurring on save.  It could be that there is something wrong with the configuration of the project that is causing a "Refresh Dependencies" over and over again.

What is the feedback that you are getting that tells you there is a full build occurring?

Take a look at what is going on in the console view when this is happening, also look at the Progress view.  Both will tell you if there are any grails-specific processes happening.

Lastly, have a peak at the error log and see if there are any relevant entries.  With a little more information, we can probably figure out what is going on.

Comment: It looks you are right in that it is refreshing dependencies because when I save it runs this in the console: 

Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/...grails-1.3.7/

Base Directory: /home/.../Source/trunk
`Resolving dependencies...`
Dependencies resolved in 7760ms.

Since then, I closed Eclipse and reopened it, and now I can't even get to the point that I was at before as I am getting basic errors.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167950/groovy-grails-unable-to-resolve-class

Comment: I am not sure how, but this has been resolved.  I think it had to do with getting rid of the VMware vFabric tc Server project that was installed when I installed STS, but I really am not sure.  Can I pick your brain about other stuff as well?  I still have a multitude of errors just trying to get this project running.

Comment: Best thing is to ask a few more questions and link them to this question.  I'll answer the other ones if I can.  Or perhaps someone else will.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Here is another question if you have the time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170040/grails-1-0-3-upgrade-problems