# Groovy/Grails - Unable to Resolve Class

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to build a Grails project in STS and am getting many error messages of the form: `Groovy:unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder` as well as others like `Groovy:unable to resolve class org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService`
.  I have Grails 1.3.7 selected in the Project Properties, but I don't see an item for 'Grails Depedencies' like I do when I create a sample project.  Is this the problem?  How can I add it back in?

Comment: Do you see these errors while you're editing classes, or just when you're trying to run the project?

Comment: @Kaleb Brasee - When I try to do a build.  Also, I think I just resolved the ConfigurationHolder errors by Refreshing Dependencies, which created the 'Grails Dependencies' in my project.  I am still getting the AuthenticateService error, despite the fact that I have the acegi plugin in my project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know why, but here are the steps I took to solve the problem:

1. Right click on the project and go to Grails Tools -> Enable Dependency Management
2. Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies.  This correctly added the 'Grails Dependencies' library.
3. I still had plugin errors.  I for some reason had to uninstall them and then reinstall them for the project to realize they were there.

Comment: I have a similar error "Unable to resolve class" on external libraries such as import com.beust.jcommander.JCommander. I am using Gradle but no Grails. How can I let my Groovy project locate the external libraries?

Answer (score 7):

**For anyone who is using Grails >= 2.4**

If you are using Grails 2.4 and above, use `grails.util.Holders` instead of `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder`.

Read the doc [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) section '**Static Holder**'

> Classes The following deprecated classes have been
>   removed from Grails 2.4.x:
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.support.GrailsResourceLoaderHolder
>   If you or any plugins you have installed are using these classes you
>   will get a compilation error. The problem can be rectified by updating
>   to new plugins and using grails.util.Holders instead.

Answer (score 2):

If "Refresh Dependencies" has done all it can for you (as you indicate in your comment on the question), try disabling and re-enabling dependencies.  You might try refreshing dependencies again afterward if the Acegi plugin still isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way solved me this issue when i moved my workspace from Windows OS to Ubuntu , go to

```
yourWorkSpace -->yourGrailsProject-->setting folder --> org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.prefs,
```

then check all the grails paths are correct or not , because in my case all were pointing to windows paths ..

Hope this solve.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue: "Unable to resolve class GrailsTestCase". I checked Grails Tools of my project and observed Dependency Management was already enabled (IDE - GGTS). I just disabled Dependency Management, refreshed and enabled it again. This solved the issue for me.